# pivot tables in database with sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, pivot

I need a database that support pivots to get pivot columns with sqlalchemy, something like that:

```
# find all possible values of the pivot
pivot_values = map(
    operator.itemgetter(0),
    select([pivot_on], from_obj=[report]).distinct().execute()
)

# build the new pivot columns
new_columns = [
    pivot_func(case([(pivot_on == value, column)])).label("%s %s" % (value, column))
    for value in pivot_values
    for column in pivot_columns
]

return select(
    non_pivot_columns + new_columns,
    from_obj=[report],
    group_by=group_by
)
```

Comment: Given the question is old, just wondering any updates with recent SQL Alchemy ?

Answer (score 1):

I use the following recipe [link text](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/334695/). I get the data and then pivot.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old, but postgres now does pivoting: http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2013/06/27/Pivoting-in-Postgres

Presumably you would have to use sa.sql.func.crosstab etc in sqlalchemy.  Guess you could map the crostabbed select to an object in the ORM and the pull the data out like that if you wanted.